# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 115: ordinal not in range(128) while converting Rdd into Dataframe: Pyspark:Azure

Tags: azure, pyspark

Getting an error while converting my csv to a dataframe in pyspark.

```
read_rdd = sc.textFile("path to my container/myfile.csv")  
intermediate_rdd = read_rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x, delimiter=","))  
header=intermediate_rdd.first()  
data_1 = intermediate_rdd.filter(lambda row : row != header).toDF(header)  
data_1.show(5)
```

## error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 115: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
read_rdd = sc.textFile("path/to/file")
intermediate_rdd = read_rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x, delimiter=","))
data = intermediate_rdd.filter(lambda row : row != header).toDF(header)
data.show(20)
```